# Spring test closes contexts only after all tests in test suite are run

Tags: java, spring, testng, integration-testing, spring-test

Suppose we have tests written as follows (in separate files):

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeBeansProvider.class, FunnyCatBeansProvider.class})
public class CatsTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {(...)}

@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeBeansProvider.class, FunnyCatBeansProvider.class})
public class CatTest2 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {(...)}

@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeBeansProvider.class, DogBeansProvider.class})
public class DogsTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {(...)}
```

I don't want to complicate things so let's us all pretend for now that all of these tests print something like "Test #no execution completed.".

Also let's have such method defined in SomeBeansProvider.class

```
@EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)
public void onContextClose(final ContextClosedEvent contextClosedEvent) {
   log.info("Context closed.");
}
```

If you execute these tests (using TestNG runner) you will see console output similar to this:

1. Test 1 execution completed.
2. Test 2 execution completed.
3. Test 3 execution completed.
4. Context closed.
5. Context closed.

Since CatTest and CatTest2 have identical contexts only one will be created for them, and one additional for DogTest.

The problem is that I want contexts be closed just after they are no longer needed. I wonder if it's possible to automatically group tests somehow during execution so there are no multiple context instances at the same time. So I want output to look similar to this:

1. Test 1 execution completed.
2. Test 2 execution completed.
3. Context closed.
4. Test 3 execution completed.
5. Context closed.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Any reason not to leverage the `@DirtiesContext` annotation?

Comment: @DirtiesContext will destroy my context every single time so it would be like:

Test 1 execution completed.
Context closed.
Test 2 execution completed.
Context closed.
Test 3 execution completed.
Context closed.

I want to take advantage of spring caching my beans.

Comment: You want to take advantage of the beans being cached *sometimes*, though.  It may also beg a slightly different structure of how your code is tested if you want that, but `@DirtiesContext` would get you 50% there (which is why I also didn't codify it as an answer).

Comment: No you cannot as there is no strict order in which the tests are run. Hence what you want is simply not possible. All the context will be cached (default max 32 different ones if I remember correctly) and will be destroyed after all tests are run (as that is when the test manager will be destroyed) or when there is a 33rd context being loaded then the oldest will be destroyed.

Comment: I would mark your answer as accepted if you would post it in separate post. (Makoto, M.Deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum btw. is there 1 a possibility to change number of contexts cached at the same time? For example from 32 to 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the below Spring annotation in our test case to make it either at class level or Method-level context close.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

> For your scenario you can do like this, You can use
>   @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) at class level,and
>   annotate @DirtiesContext(methodMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) 
>   at each test case wherever you want to close the context. and keep the
>   all the related test cases either first or last in class according to
>   the Ascending order convention so that they will run consecutively so
>   that they will be using the same context(without @DirtiesContext).

Comment: Won't this break caching/reusing context mechanism?

Comment: It will break that,if we annotate like that.Is there any way you can group the test-cases in a separate test class

Comment: You can use @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM(Select your option)) at class level and keep the all the related test cases either first or last in class,and annotate @DirtiesContext at each test case level.Can you try this?

Comment: May be you can use MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING as explained in the above comment,Rename the test cases in the order which they can come in a group

Comment: Updated the answer as per the comments!

Comment: So I have to manually manage context creation and destroy, and group my tests accordingly. Not exactly a silver bullet, but thanks.

Comment: Not the best..but it could almost meet your need.If you want fine grained control on this context usage optimized way,you can manage them in separate test-cases!

Comment: Thanks for your help!